# Quickest way to sync video taken with Android to computer

Tags: video, instant-upload

I'm taking a video on my Nexus 5 and I want to view it on my computer immediately afterward. What's the quickest way to do that? Here are the options I know about, please tell me if there's something faster.

- **Connect the phone to the computer with a USB cable:** Transfer would be blazing fast, but having to connect the phone physically would suck.
- **Use Dropbox's auto-upload to get that video automatically to my Dropbox:** This is great in that there's no need for fiddling, but it takes way too long, as Dropbox is not smart enough to transfer the file directly from phone to computer through the LAN, but rather first uploads the entire file to the Dropbox servers, which can take hours. (The file is a few hundred MB big.)
- **Use AirDroid.** The upload transfer is reasonable, but having to turn on the app, go to the browser, navigate to the file in their interface... That's annoying.

Isn't there a way to have the video automatically transferred to my computer over LAN after it's taken? Or better yet, while it is being taken, to make it even faster?

Answer (score 0):

All three are viable options that I have personally used. I have found that connecting via USB is the fastest and most reliable. (By reliable, I am referring to control over the transfer; with Dropbox you will sometimes wait for it to sync.)